# Rails DB not seeding. Am suspicious of my syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to seed my database with some fake data, but it's not working as planned. The app creates playlists.  I think I've got it modelled correctly, but when I try to seed the database, I get this error:

```
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Playlist::PlaylistSong
```

When I run a trace, I find that it doesn't like the code below (specifically the second to last line):

```
my_playlist = Playlist.create!(:name => "my_playlist")
10.times do |n|
  my_playlist.songs.create!(:name => "song #{n+1}")
end
```

My models are set up so that a playlist has many songs through a table called "playlist_songs" and songs have many playlists through the same table.

Here are my models.

```
class Playlist < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  has_many :playlist_songs
  has_many :songs, :through => :playlist_songs
 end

class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  has_many :playlist_songs
  has_many :playlists, :through => :playlist_songs
end

class PlaylistSongs < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :song
  belongs_to :playlist
end
```

My theory is that the code "my_playlist.songs" is actually a collection and that's why the create method is failing.  But I'm not sure.  Am I right?  If so, what's the syntax I should be using?

Ben

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your model name is incorrect. `PlaylistSongs` should be `PlaylistSong`

Comment: That was it.  Great eye! Thanks!